# Matrix calculus for dot product

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-optimization, matrix-calculus

I'm trying to maximize for below objective function for vector $X$.

$S \cdot X - \|BX - B_0\|_2 - \|X\|_2 $

Where $S \cdot X$ is a dot product between vector $S$ (known values) and vector X. $B$ is a matrix.

So obviously $\|BX - B_0\|_2 + \|X\|_2$ part can be differentiated. Can we differentiate the $S \cdot X$ part so I can hopefully get a closed-form solution (that will make my life easier than using an optimizer)? Or is there a way to formulate the problem in other forms?

[EDIT] Thanks all the comments. I got it now. But if I want to enforce some sparsity, to make the function

$S \cdot X - \|BX - B_0\|_2 - \|X\| $, does it have a closed-form solution?

Comment: Yes, the derivative will be $S$ or $S^T$ depending on your convention.

Comment: It should be something like $\;X = (I+B^TB)^{-1}(B^TB_0+\tfrac 12S)$

Comment: Introducing sparsity constraints ($l_0,l_1$) will mean there is no explicit solution. But since your current problem is convex, if you use the convex $l_1$ (or for matrices, nuclear norm), then you still have a convex problem, easily solved using a variety of iterative schemes

Comment: Both matrices and vectors in uppercase. Confusing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's use a naming convention where uppercase letters represent matrices, lowercase letters represent vectors, and Greek letters are scalars.

The elementwise sign function $\,g = {\rm sign}(x)\,$ can be used to expand the ${\tt1}$-norm.

The constituent functions and their derivatives are
$$\eqalign{
\alpha &= s^Tx \qquad&\partial_x\alpha = s \\
\beta &= \|Bx-b_0\|_2^2  \qquad&\partial_x\beta = 2B^T(Bx-b_0) \\
\lambda &= \|x\|_{1} = g^Tx  \qquad&\partial_x\lambda = g \\
}$$
Put all of the pieces together to create the full function.
$$\eqalign{
\phi &= \alpha - \beta - \lambda \\
\partial_x\phi
 &= \partial_x\alpha - \partial_x\beta - \partial_x\lambda \\
 &= s - 2B^TBx + 2B^Tb_0 - g \\
}$$
Set the derivative to zero and solve for $x$.
$$\eqalign{
B^TBx &= B^Tb_0 +\tfrac 12(s-g) \\
x &= (B^TB)^{-1}\left(B^Tb_0 +\tfrac 12(s-g)\right) \\
}$$
There are two potential problems with this closed-form solution:

- $\|Bx-b_0\|_2\,$ was changed to $\,\|Bx-b_0\|_2^2$

  $\,\partial_x\lambda\,$ does not exist when any component of $x$ equals zero